# Alphabet tree in assembler jump doesnt work

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have a problem with assember code (8086 16bit), I want it to write on screen a tree of A-Z digits, it should stop after X wait for a key press and later show Y and Z. I have this code:

```
    Progr           segment
                assume  cs:Progr, ds:dane, ss:stosik

start:          mov     ax,dane
                mov     ds,ax
                mov     ax,stosik
                mov     ss,ax
                mov     sp,offset szczyt
mov bx, 27 ;counter_rows
rows:

  ;here I write space
  mov cx, bx ; counter_space = counter_rows + 14
  add cl, 14
  mov ah, 02h
  mov dl, 32 ;space
  space:
    int 21h
  loop space

  ;here I write letters
  mov cl, 55 ;counter_char = 55 - counter_rows * 2
  sub cl, bl
  sub cl, bl
  mov dl, 65 + 27 ;code_char = 'A' + 27 - counter_rows
  sub dl, bl
  letters:
    int 21h
  loop letters

  ;here I go to another line(enter)
  mov dl, 0ah
  int 21h

  dec bx
  mov cx,3 
  cmp cx,bx ;is bx 3
  JNZ rows
  dec ah ; wait for a key
  int 21h

dec ah ;02h - 1 = 01h; wait for a key before end a program
int 21h

mov ax,4c00h ;set ah and al in one go and ends programo
int 21h

Progr           ends

dane            segment

dane            ends

stosik          segment
                dw    100h dup(0)
szczyt          Label word
stosik          ends

end start
```

I guess that the problem is JZ ifnull jump - I used it to stop screen after X and wait for a key press but it doesn't work as I thought it will.
Thanks in advance for help

Comment: The ifnull will be trig erred anyway even if it is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

You should probably change your code:

```
 dec bx
 mov cx,3 
 cmp cx,bx
 JZ ifnull
 ifnull:
 dec ah
 int 21h
 jnz rows
```

with this 1:

```
 dec bx
 push cx
 mov cx,3
 cmp cx,bx
 jnz rows ;will jupm to rows if not z
 dec ah   ;will continue the flow (if z)
 int 21h
```

to accomplish so , you need to put 3 in CX somewhere before rows and push it inside the rows before you change it

```
 ;"I need to do rows 2 times after successful ifnull"
pop cx
pop cx;u need to push cx before rows somewhere
dec cx
cmp cx,0
jb rows
```

after edit:

```
dec ah ; wait for a key
int 21h
```

this 1 is wrong:

```
 dec ah ;02h - 1 = 01h; wait for a key before end a program
 int 21h
```

earlier you moved 02h to ah , but already decremented it , here:

```
  dec ah ; wait for a key     -> here it is 01h
  int 21h

  dec ah ;02h - 1 = 01h; wait for a key before end a program -> Now it is 01h - 1 = 00h
  int 21h
```

regardless the first `dec ah` is in a loop

so you better just swap this line with `mov ah,01h`

Comment: Now it stops after X (which is great) but after get a key the matrix go on, i guess there is infinitive loop somewhere, maybe last jnz rows doesn't work?

Comment: Just remove the last `JNZ rows` :) I moved it to the line after the `cmp`

Comment: when i will remove it i will never get Y and Z becouse program will freeze after getting a key

Comment: @lol2x I didn't touch assembly for 5 years , probably you do have a logical problem there , if you want me to help you , then put a comments in your code so I can know what every line does , and then I will be able to help you.

Comment: It ends the program, problem is after getting a key, our loop dont go to the start to write Y and Z

Comment: @lol2x Thats right , because it doesn't (if you remove `jnz rows`) and again comment what your code does and i will help you , other wise it will take me hours to remember assembly ... and I won't do it , if you can explain where do you get the keys and what are you doing in loops I will be helpful

Comment: yup that was a place where code freezes. Now we have only one problem, after getting the enter (this one after jnz rows) we should write Y and Z line, and to do it we need to jump to the rows again.

Comment: Yes i can use only registers

Comment: @lol2x why do you check if BX is 3 ? and what register can I use ?

Comment: Coz when bx is 3 the last digit is X (is is 24 line 27-24=3) you can use cx for example coz it is user only in comparition

Comment: @lol2x he point is you need to jump to rows right ?
but you don't want to jump there infinite times ,
you want to jump there only 3 times for X Y Z right ?

if so , you should use some unused register (or define a variable)
to count how much times you are jumping to rows

Comment: I need to 'do'  rows twice after succesful ifnull and key pressed

Answer (score 1):

I changed as little as possible:

```
...
  dec bx
  cmp bx, 1
  je finish
  mov cx,3
  cmp cx,bx ;is bx 3
  JNZ rows

  mov ah, 1 ; wait for a key
  int 21h

  jmp rows

finish:

mov ah, 1 ; wait for a key before end a program
 int 21h

mov ax,4c00h ;set ah and al in one go and ends programo
int 21h
```

Comment: You've got +1 from me :) I didn't see that I can actually just use bx to count when to go to finish :)